# Clarification of SAMBA configuration basics

Tags: networking, samba

Please help me with some very basic concepts with SAMBA organization. I understand the logic for the need of setting up server and client on the respective computers for sending and receiving data and know that the communication/data is broadcast by the router.

What I  am not sure of  is the role of the router needing to be configured with a WORK GROUP , an ACCOUNT also a FOLDER.

I’m guessing is that the WORK GROUP , ACCOUNT  and FOLDER  names, etc be identically defined on all computers that want to share so that the router can deliver to the correct machine???  That appears to be logical but I never had seen an explanation.

Comment: Not really a question for here. You can start learning about Samba from this site. https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch01.html